# c# - How to start a process from a list of programs that can handle a certain file extension?

Tags: c#, process, registry

I am writing a program where I have a list of images with various formats (.png, .jpg, .bmp, .ico...) and so far I've been able to obtain a list of the shell commands associated with each files, like so:

```
"\"C:\\Program Files\\Paint.NET\\PaintDotNet.exe\" \"%1\""
"\"C:\\Program Files\\GIMP 2\\bin\\gimp-2.8.exe\" \"%1\""
"C:\\Windows\\System32\\rundll32.exe \"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Photo Viewer\\PhotoViewer.dll\", ImageView_Fullscreen %1"
"\"C:\\Windows\\system32\\mspaint.exe\" /pt \"%1\" \"%2\" \"%3\" \"%4\""    
"\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\PDFCreator\\pdfcreator.exe\" -IF\"%1\"" string
```

I'm not sure this is the right thing to have, but that's what I have so far. When using:

```
Process.Start(completeProgramPath);
```

The program is never found, unless I use something like

```
Process.Start("mspaint.exe");
```

I want to be able to specify which program the operating system should use. What am I doing wrong? Is it my list of program that doesn't point to the right thing, or am I not using Process.Start(); correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to open the default program for each image, then just provide the file name as the only argument to the `Process.Start` method, omit the executable path, and the operating system will look in the registry so you don't have to:

```
Process.Start("C:\some\picture.jpg");
```

This will open the default program for the `*.jpg` extension, and pass the path of the file as an argument to it.

If you want to specify the program, then you should use the `Process.Start(string, string)` overload in which you specify the path of the executable as the first parameter, and the path of the file as the second parameter.

If you try to use the exact values in the registry keys, it won't work because they have the `"%1"` added to the paths and the rundll32 keys have additional arguments.  The point is that you will have to alter the strings you get out of the registry keys before you pass them to the `Start` method.

**Example:**
`"\"C:\\Program Files\\Paint.NET\\PaintDotNet.exe\" \"%1\""` will need to become:
`"C:\Program Files\Paint.NET\PaintDotNet.exe"`

Comment: I want to be able to specify which program I want the operating system to use.

Comment: Works like a charm! I can't vote your answer up because I don't have reputation, but I marked it as the accepted answer. Thank you for your help.